# SQL Conditional joins, data inheritance

Tags: sql, join, conditional-statements

I need to implement a data inheritance logic, based on a dynamic tree, with a fixed depth of 3.

```
Output 1
--Output 1.1
--Output 1.2
----Ouptut 1.2.1
----Output 1.2.2
--Output 1.3
Ouput 2
-- Output 2.1
-- Output 2.2
-- etc.
```

So I have an object defined as followed:

```
Object
-id
-createdAt
```

And the data attached to the object

```
ObjectData
-owner_id (fk to the object)
-output_id (fk to the output)
-name (this is the real data)
```

What I am trying to do is retrieve a list of Object, inner join the ObjectData base on owner_id/ouput_id, but if no ObjectData with given output_id exists, join the ObjectData of parent output.

At the moment, with my basic SQL query, if the object_data has no entry with a given output, it is not returned, which is how works INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT c.*, d.name FROM object c
INNER JOIN object_data d ON c.id = d.owner_id AND d.ouput_id = ?
```

What I am trying to achieve is to avoid having to create a new object_data entry when data is fully inherited, to optimize storage size, and to avoid huge inserts when adding a new output.

I must also be able to order the query on a object_data field.

Thank you !

EDIT:
Thanks to Gordon Linoff I think that coalesce is a solution for my problem, but according to mysql doc, coalesce will return first non null.
In my case, if the row exists, I want to return its value wether it is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want.  The following SQL joins in both the object data and the parent's object data, and then chooses between them in the `select` statement:

```
select o.*, coalesce(od.name, od_parent.name)
from object o left outer join
     objectdata od_o
     on od_o.id = o.id left outer join
     objectdata od_parent
     on od_parent.id = o.parent_id
```

This may seem like unnecessary effort on the part of the database engine.  But most engines are highly optimized for joining tables together, so performance probably is not an issue -- especially if you have the right indexes on the tables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that seems a good solution !
What if happens if a row exists, but the value is null, will it return the parent data ? that is not what I want.